# 2006 Pontiac G6, 3.5 V6 - ABS and Traction Control Lights in Pontiac G6

Tags: electrical, brakes, abs, warning-light, traction-control

I own a 2006 Pontiac G6, 3.5 V6 with 155,000 miles. I was coming to a gentle stop when the ABS activated, and the brake pedal vibrated as though I lost traction. Before accelerating, both ABS and T/C lights came on.

It was 40℉, wet roads, and the water temp was normal.

I checked the fuses, and everything was intact.

Is there anything I can do to fix the issue that doesn't require me to see a mechanic or get a computer reading from the system?

Over the past few days, the abs/tc lights have been turning off. They come on when I go over bumps, starting the car, and turn off when I push on the connector attached to the ABS module. Does anyone have a diagram of the connector and where each wire should be?

Comment: The BCM would have nothing to do with it, as it controls things like interior lights, radio, and alarm system. The ABS has its own computer. Unless you get the computer read, there's not much we can do to help you. Diagnosis is near impossible without it.

Comment: If you goto an auto parts store they will usually do a scan of your vehicle with an ODBII compliant scanner.  You can give us the codes and we can provide a recommendation for a solution.  Do you have any codes you can provide?

Answer (score 2):

There is a recall of your vehicle for the BCM (Body Control Module) which is a type of ECU.  This effects your traction control and cruise control as well as brakes according to this NTSB recall link.

[*Recall Link for Your Vehicle*](http://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/owners/SearchResults;jsessionid=3KMJWGGCHc58PMJ3kp4nfG2gh80QYcHg4mncwwfjgH4Kt2jKmLyk!182953998?prodType=V&searchType=PROD&targetCategory=A&searchCriteria.model=G6&stats=208761%2C7%2C4%2C1512%2C89%2CG6&makeStats=&jsonBaseURL=%2Fdownloads%2Ffolders%2F&searchCriteria.model_yr=2006&searchCriteria.make=PONTIAC&searchCriteria.prod_ids=208761)

> **SUMMARY:**
>
> General Motors LLC (GM) is recalling certain model year 2004-2012 Chevrolet Malibu vehicles manufactured May 16, 2003, through October 11, 2012, 2004-2007 Malibu Maxx vehicles manufactured June 25, 2003, through April 5, 2007, 2005-2010 Pontiac G6 vehicles manufactured May 26, 2004, through January 4, 2010, and 2007-2010 Saturn Aura vehicles manufactured April 24, 2006, through May 26, 2009. In the affected vehicles, increased resistance in the Body Control Module (BCM) connection may result in voltage fluctuations in the Brake Apply Sensor (BAS) circuit. These fluctuations can cause one or more of these conditions: the brake lights to illuminate without the brake pedal being pushed; the brake lights to not illuminate when the pedal is pushed; difficulty disengaging the cruise control; moving the gear shifter out of the 'PARK' position without pushing the brake; and disablement of crash avoidance features such as traction control, electronic stability control, and panic braking assist features.
>
> **CONSEQUENCE:**
>
> Any of the above failure conditions increases the risk of a crash.
>
> **REMEDY:**
>
> GM will notify owners, and dealers will attach the wiring harness to the BCM with a spacer, apply dielectric lubricant to both the BCM and harness connector and the BAS and harness connector, and will relearn the brake pedal home position, free of charge. The manufacturer distributed an Interim letter to customers on July 14, 2014. The recall began on August 18, 2014. Owners may contact General Motors customer service at 1-800-222-1020 (Chevrolet), 1-800-762-2737 (Pontiac), 1-800-553-6000 (Saturn). GM's number for this recall is 13036.
>
> **NOTES:**
>
> Owners may also contact the National Highway Traffic Safety Administration Vehicle Safety Hotline at 1-888-327-4236 (TTY 1-800-424-9153), or go to www.safercar.gov.

Answer (score 0):

I'm at 162,000 and the abs/tc lights are on constantly. I scanned the codes and there's a fault in the right front wheel speed circuit. I played around with the wires and the lights went out. My understanding is that there's a recall out for the wiring harness.